# Ruby FIzz-buzz can't push numbers to an array

Tags: ruby, fizzbuzz

So, as you can see, I'm not well versed in Ruby so it helps if you keep your responses primitive, instead of using short cuts.

I am able to get my fizz-buzz to work in the first example, I added the absolute method to handle negative input and used variables to easily accommodate changing 3 and 5 to other numbers. But, I can't push the results to an array, I just get '1' as a result. Does anyone see where I went wrong?

```
# not array - works
class Fixnum
  define_method(:fizz_buzz) do
    fizz = 3
    buzz = 5

    1.upto(self.abs) do |i|
      if (i % fizz == 0) && (i % buzz == 0)
        puts "fizz-buzz"
      elsif (i % fizz == 0)
        puts "fizz"
      elsif (i % buzz == 0)
        puts "buzz"
      else
        puts i
      end
    end
  end
end


# push to array - doesn't work
class Fixnum
  define_method(:fizz_buzz) do
    fizz = 3
    buzz = 5
    array = []

    1.upto(self.abs) do |i|
      if (i % fizz == 0) && (i % buzz == 0)
        array.push("fizz-buzz")
      elsif (i % fizz == 0)
        array.push("fizz")
      elsif (i % buzz == 0)
        array.push("buzz")
      else
        array.push(i)
      end
    end
  end
end
=> 1
```

WW

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return your array at the end of the function.

```
class Fixnum
  define_method(:fizz_buzz) do
    fizz = 3
    buzz = 5
    array = []

    1.upto(self.abs) do |i|
      if (i % fizz == 0) && (i % buzz == 0)
        array.push("fizz-buzz")
      elsif (i % fizz == 0)
        array.push("fizz")
      elsif (i % buzz == 0)
        array.push("buzz")
      else
        array.push(i)
      end
    end
    array
  end
end
```

In ruby, the last line in the function is used as your return value. When you call `1.upto` it runs the given block the specified number of times and then returns the `1`. Adding `array` to the end makes it so it will return the array.

Comment: Damnit! I always keep forgetting that part. Thanks @rdubya